# Difference between linear regression in statistic and backdoor.linear_regression in (DoWhy) causality

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, causality

I have just started to deal with causality. I mostly use DoWhy for this. Earlier, I read about various statistical algorithms based on various linear models, such as DoWhy's estimation method. If I only look at this method, how does it know more than other statistical tools? What is the causality in this?

[This question is similar to mine.](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_is_causal_analysis_different_from_regression_analysis#:%7E:text=In%20causality%20analysis%2C%20the%20interaction,variable%20and%20independent%20variable%2Fs.)

Comment: Since this is a very broad question, I recommend reading for example chapter 1-3 of the [Elements of causal inference](http://web.math.ku.dk/~peters/jonas_files/ElementsOfCausalInference.pdf).